# Botkit : mutation of the BotkitMessage object throughout middlewares

Tags: bots, middleware, chatbot, botkit, ingest

The user sends `Hi there !` (stored in `message.text`) from the chatbot UI; However, the `ConversationPlugin's ingest` middleware mutates `message.text`  to the value `Hello`. My question is : why isn't this value kept by the time the `receive`  middleware runs ? (cf. logs below) This behaviour is crucial for my app. I need to make sure the botkit message remembers/keeps my mutations  all along the way (all along the turn) !

`[2020-05-16T11:23:47.130] [DEBUG] -  [ConversationPlugin.ingest()] before triggering the event 'userMessage' => message.text ==> Hi there !
[2020-05-16T11:23:47.132] [DEBUG] -  [ConversationPlugin.ingest()] after triggering the event 'userMessage' => message.text ==> Hello
[2020-05-16T11:23:47.142] [DEBUG] -  [ConversationPlugin.receive()] message.text => Hi there !
[2020-05-16T11:23:47.143] [DEBUG] -  [ConversationPlugin.receive()] The message text is =>  Hi there !`

Could you please help me understand/solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

It is very difficult to say what is happening inside your code without seeing it.

This code works as expected - the ingest middleware changes the text, and that change is available inside the receive middleware:

````
module.exports = function(controller) {

  controller.middleware.ingest.use((bot, message, next) => {
    console.log('INGEST', message.text);
    message.text = 'INGESTING ' + message.text;
    next();
  });


controller.middleware.receive.use((bot, message, next) => {
  console.log('RECEIVED', message.text);
  next();
});


}```
````